# Health & Fitness stores bicycling workout as a run

Tags: 8.1, apps, nokia-lumia-1520

I've started using my bicycle get to work and I thought let's try out [MSN Health & Fitness](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/health-fitness/cbb8c3bd-99e8-4176-ad8c-95ec6a3641c2).

I got on my bike, started the app and did the following:

- Clicked <kbd>GPS Tracker</kbd>
- Selected *Bicyling*
- Clicked <kbd>Start workout</kbd>

After 30 minutes of cycling I had arrived and stopped my workout and the app said that I'd burned 490 calories. I restarted the app and looked at the history. It displayed my last exercise as a running exercise.

Is there any way to solve this? Or am I maybe forgetting some steps in the process of starting a new exercise?